# Error converting bytecode to dex, PARSE ERROR, InvokeDynamic not supported - Instagram library

Tags: java, android, instagram, android-multidex

I have a problem. I'm still getting this error trying to add library for Instagram 'https://github.com/brunocvcunha/instagram4j':

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: 
Cause: PARSE ERROR: 
InvokeDynamic not supported 
...while preparsing cst 005c at offset 00000195 
...while parsing org/brunocvcunha/instagram4j/Instagram4j.class 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. 
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex 
'C:\Users\hp\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files 2.1\org.brunocvcunha.instagram4j\instagram4j\1.4\e86d0ec82fb3eb4225b983e6dc14db048005bc9b\instagram4j-1.4.jar' to 'C:\Users\hp\Downloads\appName\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\instagram4j-1.4_ea292e8a2c317dbd8ab0226ff9507ee97ac0794b'
```